# Concrete Mathematics: How do we figure out the constrains of summations when using multiplication by summation factor method?

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

In chapter 2.2 of Concrete Mathematics, the authors introduced the usage of summation factor to convert recurrence to summation. The idea is to multiply $s_n$ on both sides of the recurrence relation of the form $a_n T_n = b_n T_{n-1} + c_n$ to obtain $s_n a_n T_n = s_n b_n T_{n-1} + s_n c_n$. If we select $s_n b_n = s_{n-1} a_{n-1}$, and let $S_n = s_n a_n T_n$, then we get $S_n = S_{n-1} + s_n c_n$, which can be expressed in terms of a sum easily.

Here's my question. When they are solving for the quick sort recurrence $C_0 = C_1 = 0$ and $C_n = n + 1 + \frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} C_k$, the final closed form formula have a restriction of $n > 1$. Why?

More general, how can we figure out the restriction of $n$ while using such technique?

**EDIT**

In order to solve for $C_n = n + 1 + \frac{2}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} C_k$, first multiply both sides by $n$ to obtain $nC_n = n^2 + n + 2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} C_k$. If you replace $n$ by $n-1$, we get $(n-1)C_{n-1} = (n-1)^2 + (n-1) + 2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-2} C_k$. Take note this is only valid if $n>2$. Subtract both equations, we get $nC_n =(n+1)C_{n-1}+2n$ for $n>2$, and $C_0 = C_1 = 0$ and $C_2 = 3$. From this point, the recurrence will only be valid for $n>2$, but the final solution is valid for $n>1$. Why?

Comment: The formula $C_n = n + 1 + 2/n \sum_0 ^{n-1} C_k$ is incorrect  for $n = 1$. If you plug in $1$ here, you get $C_1 = 1 + 1 + 2 C_1$ which is incompatible with $C_1 = 0$. The formula makes even less sense for $n = 0$ since you have a division by $0$. Since the formula is only valid for $n \gt 1$, any results you obtain using the formula will only apply if $n \gt 1$.

Comment: @Mark Thanks. I understood the requirement of $n>1$. However, in order to remove the summation and reciprocal function from the recurrence, they subtracted $C_{n-1}$ from $C_n$, and this results in the restriction of $n-1>1$, or $n>2$. From then on, they solve that new recurrence relation instead, so I presume the final result should works for $n>2$ only. Yet, it is valid for $n=2$ too. Is this just coincidence, or is there some justification behind this?

Comment: Fix some $n \gt 1$. Then the formula is valid. Now subtract the number $K$ from both sides. The formula is still valid. (Even if the number $K$ happens to be $C_{n-1}$). So this new formula is still valid for $n \gt 1$. The only problem that could occur is that $C_{n-1}$ maybe is undefined if $n$ is too small. But since we required $n \gt 1$, then $C_{n-1}$ is defined so there is no trouble.

Comment: @Mark I have edited the question to include the steps they took. I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough, but the reasoning you given requires that $C_{n-1}$ have is not the base case. That isn't the case in their argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The summation factor is $\frac2{n(n+1)}$, so we get $S_n=\frac2{n+1}C_n$ and $S_n=S_{n-1}+\frac4{n+1}$ for $n\ge 3$. $C_2=3$, so $S_2=\frac23C_2=2$, and

$$S_n=2+\sum_{k=3}^n\frac4{k+1}=2+4(H_{n+1}-H_3)=4H_{n+1}-\frac{16}3$$

for $n\ge 3$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
C_n&=2(n+1)H_{n+1}-\frac83(n+1)\\
&=2(n+1)\left(H_n+\frac1{n+1}\right)-\frac83n-\frac83\\
&=2(n+1)H_n-\frac83n-\frac23\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

for $n\ge 3$.

The *derivation* is valid only for $n\ge 3$, but the *expression* $(1)$ might by good fortune be valid for smaller values of $n$, and one should always test. Here we find that for $n=2$ it evaluates to

$$2\cdot3\cdot\frac32-\frac{16}3-\frac23=9-6=3\;,$$

which actually is $C_2$. However, at $n=1$ it evaluates to

$$2\cdot2\cdot1-\frac83-\frac23=4-\frac{10}3\ne 0=C_1\;,$$

so the closed form

$$C_n=2(n+1)H_n-\frac83n-\frac23$$

is valid precisely for $n\ge 2$. Its validity for $n=2$ doesn’t follow from the derivation: it follows from an independent verification after the fact.

Comment: I attempt the derive a weaker statement by allowing the base case to be $T_{n_0}$, and I got that the closed form for the recurrence is only valid for $n \ge n_0+2$. So in the end, I decided to let it go and went with the logic of "might by good fortune be valid for smaller values of $n$". Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @nexolute: You're welcome.